# Вопросы о Django, React

Tags: django, reactjs

Я создаю некий сайт при помощи Джанго и React. На этом сайте будут различные привычные нам страницы, например: "Главная", "Другая", "О нас". На каждой из этих страниц будет реализована своя собственная функция. Собственно вопрос, мне нужно для каждой страницы создавать свое Джанго-приложение (для реализаций функций) внутри общего Джанго-проекта? Если это так, то как быть со static-файлами: например возьмем html, css, js "Главная", мне нужно разместить все подобные файлы для каждой страницы в папке templates, static? Или вообще создать несколько templates, static, что кажется мне бредом, ибо будут проблемы с указанием в settings.py путей. И где подключить React, внутри Джанго-проекта? Также я знаю, что React использует свои static, где их разместить? Если Вам показались мои вопросы глупыми, извините, я новичок и мне все это предстоит узнать)

Comment: Можете с примерами детализировать ваш вопрос?

Comment: Конечно, спасибо за интерес. Например на странице "Главная" будет какая-то лента с обновляющейся информацией, а на странице "Другое" еще какая-то функция, отличная от других страниц. Мне стоит просто создать Джанго-приложение, например "pages", в нем создать templates рядом с views.py и models.py и там хранить код (html, а в static css, js), который будет эти функции собственно реализовывать?  Дальше возьмем другое что-то, например личный кабинет пользователя, мне для реализации этой цели нужно создать тоже отдельное джанго-приложение? И еще вопрос, React подключать к Джанго-проекту же?

Comment: На React пишете нужный фронт, а на django реализуете серверную часть. Если есть большие разделы(ну на подобии админки) то можно вынести это в отдельное react приложение и отдавать его отдельно браузеру. Видимо вы попробовали смешать все в одну кучу, что не стоит делать. React при сборке преобразуется в javaScript. javaScript работает в браузере клиента, python на сервере и отвечает на запросы клиента...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, я в прошлый раз много накрутил в кучу всего, из-за этого там была каша. У меня еще возник вопрос по поводу организации static-файлов. В Джанго есть static, а в Реакт подобные файлы размещают или тоже в static или public, в чем отличия этих файлов, которые размещают в public Реакт и static Джанго? Обязательно это делать?

Comment: React и Django это 2 разных языка со своими компиляторами и сборщиками. Не стоит их мешать в одну кучу и рассматривать их надо отдельно друг от друга